# Maximum number of "True" values on any axis in a Numpy Multil-dimensional Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a multi-dimension array in Numpy with boolean values. In my case, it is a cube.

I would like to know the maximal dimension of a the smallest rectangular box containing all the `True` values. In other words, that would be the maximum distance on any axis between `True` values.

For example, if I have the following array

```py
np.array([[
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
], [
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
], [
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False,  True, False],
    [False, False,  True,  True, False],
    [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
    [False,  True, False, False, False],
], [
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
], [
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
]])
```

it would return **4** because we have a distance of 4 vertically in this "box" (or a distance of 4 between the bottom-left and upper-right values):

```
  ...
  [False False  True]
  [False  True  True]
  [ True  True  True]
  [ True False False]
  ...
```

I was thinking of the following but that sounds redundant, repetitive, and costly... and actually not exactly working :)

```py
   from itertools import product

    max_1 = max(sum(cube[:, i, j]) for i, j in product(range(3), range(3)))
    max_2 = max(sum(cube[i, :, j]) for i, j in product(range(3), range(3)))
    max_3 = max(sum(cube[i, j, :]) for i, j in product(range(3), range(3)))

    # ... and then
    max_dim = max(max_1, max_2, max_3)
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is to get the length of the largest dimension, you can use

```
max(np.ptp(d) + 1 for d in np.nonzero(a))
```

where `a` is your boolean array. The output for the array in your question is `4`. Read on if you need to get the smallest 3D bounding box for the `True` values.

---

One could use [`numpy.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) to find the indices of the `True` values in each dimension, then index the original array according to the minimum and maximum of the indices found by [`numpy.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html).

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
], [
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
], [
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, True, False],
    [False, False, True, True, False],
    [False, True, True, True, False],
    [False, True, False, False, False],
], [
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
], [
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
]])

slices = [slice(d.min(), d.max()+1) for d in np.nonzero(a)]
a[slices[0], slices[1], slices[2]]
```

The output matches your desired output.

```
array([[[False, False,  True],
        [False,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True],
        [ True, False, False]]])
```

---

This can be turned into a function to work with N-d arrays. This uses [`numpy.s_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html), which creates an index expression that can be used to get slices of an array.

```
def get_bbox_indexer(a):
    slices = tuple(slice(d.min(), d.max()+1) for d in np.nonzero(a))
    return np.s_[slices]

indexer = get_bbox_indexer(a)
a[indexer]
```

The output is the same as above

```
array([[[False, False,  True],
        [False,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True],
        [ True, False, False]]])
```

To get the size of the largest dimension with the sliced array, you can do

```
indexer = get_bbox_indexer(a)
max(a[indexer].shape)
```

Comment: You can stack the indices returned by `nonzero` to bypass the comprehension: `(np.ptp(np.stack(np.nonzero(np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4))), axis=1) + 1).max()`

Comment: `np.ptp` is indeed beautiful!

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to get the indices of `True` elements and then compute the min and max of these -- this will be your rectangle.

```
a = [...]
indices = np.array(np.where(a)).T
print(np.min(indices, axis=0), np.max(indices, axis=0))

[2 1 1] [2 4 3]
```

Then to get the max length, just subtract these two, find the max, and add 1.

```
print(np.max(np.max(indices, axis=0) - np.min(indices, axis=0)) + 1)

4
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is actually working for me but **it assumes that the `True` values are contiguous**.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
], [
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
], [
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, True, False],
    [False, False, True, True, False],
    [False, True, True, True, False],
    [False, True, False, False, False],
], [
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
], [
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False],
]])

max_axis = (np.sum(np.any(a, axis=axis), axis=1) for axis in range(3))
max_dim = max(max(m) for m in max_axis)
```

1. For each axis, detect if at least one `True` is present on the other axes
2. Count the number of such axes with True
3. Compute the max for each axis